# Bootstrap .container-fluid with ".container-like" layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `Bootstrap` website built using `.container` for the layout with an additional `CSS` property for `.container` in my site CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

I'm now trying to move to a `.container-fluid` layout so I can have full-screen background images in my divs, but at the same time I still need the actual content of my divs to have a `.container`-like layout. I have so far tried to nest a `.container` in a `.container-fluid` but this does not seem like the best solution or a good practice for that matter.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just wrap your `.container`s in a div? This will naturally have a width of 100% and have no effect on the `.container`s within - Example http://www.bootply.com/stcoJoHiwg

Comment: seems to work. how about when you want different "backgrounds" per section? do you need to create one `container` per background (e.g. [like this](http://www.bootply.com/QHl4tFXEDw))? I have a total of one container for my body, after which I section the body using `.row` divs

Comment: That's how I envisioned it working. If you have all of your content in a single container this approach won't work

Comment: i think u r making ur self confused. just wrap container with any DIV, it will work 100% bg img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wanted to do this but some of the solutions I found were more complex than needed. What I did was pretty much exactly what [uʍopǝpısdn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/746736/u%ca%8dop%c7%9dp%c4%b1sdn) has already suggested in the comments of your question, i.e. wrap `.container` in a `div`.

I created some color styles for each of the sections I needed colored:

```
.bg-black {
    background-color: #111;
}
//add more colors, even background images in a similar manner
```

And used those styles as classes of each wrapping `div`:

```
<div class="bg-black">
    <div class="container">
        //content here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bg-red">
    <div class="container">
        //other content here
    </div>
</div>
//...and so on
```

This solution obviously requires you to restructure your `HTML` to use one `.container` per section instead of one `.container` per `body`, which I found to work quite well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="wrap">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        here u can use span or u can provide the style property
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

think it should help u :)